# Failed to fetch errors when running sudo apt update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

I am using the following OS version:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

When I run `sudo apt update`, I get the following message:

```
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                               
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                                                                                 
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                                 
Ign:1 https://dl.bintray.com/etcher/debian stable InRelease                                                                                                      
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]                                                                                      
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                             
Get:7 https://dl.bintray.com/etcher/debian stable Release [3,674 B]                                                                                                                                  
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]                                                                                                                               
Hit:6 https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                       
Hit:11 https://release.memsql.com/production/debian memsql InRelease                                                                                                                                       
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu bionic InRelease                            
Ign:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages
Ign:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages
Ign:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages
Err:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Ign:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages
Ign:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages [618 kB]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages [652 kB]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe Translation-en [216 kB]
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [42.1 kB]
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [16.4 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [111 kB]
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [436 kB]
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [436 kB]
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [436 kB]
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [436 kB]
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [436 kB]
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [436 kB]
Ign:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Get:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [1,012 kB]
Get:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1,060 kB]       
Get:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe Translation-en [328 kB]
Ign:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages
Get:34 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [273 kB]
Get:35 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [211 kB]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [480 kB]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages [641 kB]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages [641 kB]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages [641 kB]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages [641 kB]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages [641 kB]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages [641 kB]
Err:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Ign:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages
Err:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Ign:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages
Fetched 181 kB in 2s (85.1 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'etcher/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'https://deb.etcher.io stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I fix these error messages?

This is my `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security universe main
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arm64` is not supposed to reside there, supposing you don't need them, you can remove it manually.

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture arm64
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed it!